# How to do these type of string pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, string

So if i was given a string like this:

```
  s1|s2|s3|s4:t1|t2|t3
```

and lets say first of all i want to separate all of 's' strings and then separate all the 't' strings.

how do i get rid of the delimiters like '|' and ':',

i know i can do basic charAt and subString but that seem like way too much work.

like i know the pattern: every string is seperated by the | is there not a way to extract strings using patterns?

can you guys show me some code please, or some hints on topics i should learn.

the way i am doing it is using multiple arraylist to hold the index's of the delimeitrs and then arraylist to store all the strings and if i want to perform an operation it would be even harder.

Comment: Split on `[:|]`

Comment: @Toto if this actually works and is one line of code. i will hit my head against the wall, i have written 50 lines of code - 4 methods.. oh my.. im gonna check this out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the String.split function:

```
String[] parts = "s1|s2|s3|s4:t1|t2|t3".split("[:|]");
// parts = { s1, s2, s3, s4, t1, t2, t3 }
```

Note that the `parts` array may not have the same size depending on the input (for example, `s1|s2` will give `{s1, s2}`.

Comment: what topic is this? is there any website or something i can search to find and learn more about this type of string manipulation and any other methods to make this type of work easy?

Comment: @asasasdada: This is called regular expression, you will find good intro at https://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: @asasasdada: these are regular expression and their syntax is defined here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

To extract any parts which has any letter and any number right after it you can use pattern

```
[a-z]\d+
```

Comment: what ..is that... explanation? what topic is it?

Comment: Sorry, man, I thought you need pattern to extract  t1, t2, s1, s2 and so on, my apologizes if I understood you wrongly